# $W$ boson $0.1$% heavier than predicted by 7$σ$?

Tags: standard-model, beyond-the-standard-model

Quite recently more and more refined experimental results pile up that put the SM under stress and tend to disprove more and more its predictive power and potentially are the start-up point of new physics beyond the SM to exist.

Last year 2021, we had the 4.2$σ$ discrepancy between prediction and actual measurement by the [g-2 Fermilab experiment](https://news.fnal.gov/2021/04/first-results-from-fermilabs-muon-g-2-experiment-strengthen-evidence-of-new-physics/) of the anomalous spin magnetic dipole moment of the muon.

At 7th of April 2022 even a more [astonishing result](https://www.quantamagazine.org/fermilab-says-particle-is-heavy-enough-to-break-the-standard-model-20220407/) was published in Science Magazine of a 7$σ$ discrepancy of the W bosons mass being about 0.1% more heavily as predicted. It seems that the  SM starts failing  as more accurate experiments are realized opening the possibility of “new physics beyond the SM” to be discovered.

What are the implications of this new finding to the SM?

Does it mean that there is a new undiscovered particle or the SM is wrong?

Comment: You want a digest of [dozens](https://arxiv.org/search/?searchtype=all&query=CDF+W+mass+anomaly&abstracts=show&size=200&order=-announced_date_first) of ambulance-chasing victims of alacrity?

Comment: One more vote needed for the question to re-open. The question was largely edited from its previous version.